# How to union a statement start with WITH?

Tags: sql, t-sql, union, common-table-expression

I want to make a union to start with WITH, but SQL server won't allow me to do that.

What will be the correct way to do it?

```
with T1 as
(select * from Table where ID in (1, 2, 3))
select * from T1
UNION
with T2 as
(select * from Table where ID in (7, 8, 9))
select * from T2
```

Comment: Aside: [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will remove duplicate rows. If there are no duplicates then `union all` will be more efficient as it won't bother with sorting and comparing rows.

Answer (score 1):

I found the syntax is

```
with T1 as (select * from Table where ID in (1, 2, 3)), 
T2 as (select * from Table where ID in (7, 8, 9))
select * from T1
UNION
select * from T2
```